# Why does the set method in Python scramble the output every-time you run it in a different file?

Tags: python, set

When I do:

```
set('zbc')
```

I get as a result:

```
{'b' , 'z' , 'c'}
```

And when I start another python code and type the same thing, I get different order? Why is that? Is there a way to get the same order everytime? thanks.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the intro tour.    This is covered in the `set` documentation and many, many places on line.  We expect you to do your research before posting here.

Comment: @SendHelp `set` doesn't maintain the order

Comment: @Prune Hey prune, thanks for your comment, aside from the "why" question - I asked if we have an option to keep the order, so this is not a "ask to ask" question..

Comment: Your second question is also covered with a straightforward browser search.

Answer (score 2):

Just read this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Sets are unordered collection.

You can use other modules like  [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
od = OrderedDict() 
od['a'] = 1
od['b'] = 2
od['c'] = 3
od['d'] = 4

for key, value in od.items(): 
    print(key, value)
```

Output :

```
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
('c', 3)
('d', 4)
```

Comment: `Ordered Sets` can also be used. I think the OP wants his answer more towards sets.

Answer (score 0):

Order in `set` is not guaranteed as they are based on hash tables and not on balanced trees.

Moreover hashing is randomized when Python starts to avoid denial of service attacks to servers: carefully crafted requests could put servers in `O(n)` search times on dictionaries making servers unable to answer in time.

`dict` on the other hand has been changed recently and it maintains the insertion order; thus if you only insert elements and later iterated the dictionary the key/value pairs will be in the same order they were when you inserted them.

Instead of a set like

```
{'c', 'b', 'z'}
```

you can use a dict like

```
{'c': None, 'b': None, 'z': None}
```

on recent CPython the key sequence will be `c`, `b` and `z` (not sure if other Python implementations already aligned on this).

Comment: is there a way to keep the order from first to last- meaning that if I type zbc the output will be {z,b,c} and when I type cbz the output will be {c,b,z} ? 
thanks for the explanation !

Comment: @SendHelp: you can use a `dict` with `None` as values; in recent cpython version this will  maintain sequence as it does for example in Javascript.

Comment: awesome, thank you!